# How to pass jQuery changes between pages

Tags: jquery

I have created some jQuery affecting a single page. This happened to change the body class tag when you click a button. The problem is when I go to different pages this body tag returns to normal. I was wondering if there is a way to preserve a change in the body tag using jQuery between pages.

I am a little new to jQuery, so I would not know what exactly to search for.

Comment: If you are planning to do this at client side then what you need to search for is *cookies* or HTML5 *client-side storage* capabilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a jQuery thing. Typically you would store your page state in a cookie and then execute code on every page that reads the cookie and reapplies the change.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am now using jQuery cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript runs in the browser, not on the server. Because the server renders each page independently (HTTP is a stateless protocol), there is no way for changes Javascript makes to the DOM to persist across HTTP requests.

If you want to make a persistent change, you will need to communicate back to the server. For example, with jQuery, you could use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) to send a message back to the server that the body class has been changed, and have the server send back new markup including the class on subsequent page loads. Or, you could set a cookie using Javascript, and have the server check for the cookie when seeing if it should render the changed class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax `load();` function to load this page in another page with the effects carried forward.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you would use cookies for to store a value while in the session, to denote a boolean for your jquery button event as triggered or not triggered.